# MIUI newest version displays annoying message popups

Tags: xiaomi, miui

Whenever someone writes me a message on hangouts or messenger, I get this popup:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

How can I disable this? It's very annoying when I'm watching a movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just turn off all notifications for the applications.

You need to swipe down your notification bar and then long press on each notification, it should open up a menu for disabling all notifications, if this doesn't work then you'll need to open up the applications individually and thoroughly go through the settings of each app, most likely you'll have an option to turn these type of notifications off.

Comment: For miui goto settings app>notifications & status bar>App notifications>YourAnnoyingAppName>Show notification(turn off the toggle).